# Automator service to print a relative path of selected files printing everything twice

Tags: finder, automator, services

I have a service that copy the selected file's paths and put them on the clipboard.

It kinda works, except everything gets printed twice.

The service is like this:  Get selected files from Finder > run script (as arguments) > copy to clipboard.

The script is:

```
for f in "$@"
do
   echo $f | cut -c 34-
done
```

I cut some starting characters because I need the path relative to some specific folder, and the size is always the same. I need this to submit the files I changed when committing files to a svn.

Here's an example, I selected three files, ran the service and this is the output:

```
layouts_index/f1/cadastro/confirmar.php
layouts_index/f2/cadastro/confirmar.php
cadastro/confirmar.php
layouts_index/f1/cadastro/confirmar.php
layouts_index/f2/cadastro/confirmar.php
cadastro/confirmar.php
```

Is this a problem in the script? Is there a way to fix it using the script or do I need applescript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, think I got it. This is what I initially set up:

[image]

But when I ran that service, I only got a single list of files (which is what you want, but not what you were getting).

<sup>Footnote: when you’re having problems with an Automator workflow, a screenshot is really useful.</sup>

So then I decided to modify the "Service receives selected" field:

[image]

and if you try to run that from within Automator, then you get an error message:

[image]

When I go and run that service from outside Automator, I get the duplicated paths that you’re seeing.
So I think your list of selected items is getting picked up twice: once by "Service receives selected", and again by "Get Selected Finder Items".
When Automator goes to copy to the clipboard, it gets the list twice.

**If you remove one of them, then you should get what you want.**

Comment: Removed the Get Selected Files from Finder and now it works perfectly. Thanks.